On the right regular representation $\rho:GL(n,A)\rightarrow\mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{C}}(L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega))$
Let $F$ be an algebraic number field, $A$ its adele ring. Let $\omega$ be a unitary character, that is, a continuous group homomorphism $\omega:A^\times/F^\times\rightarrow C^\times$.
Let $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$ be the space of measurable function on $GL(n,A)$ with respect to Haar measure and that satisfy
$$\phi\left(\left(
\begin{matrix}
z & 0 \\
0 & z \\
\end{matrix}
\right)g\right)=\omega(z)\phi(g),\ \ \ \ \ z\in A^\times,$$
$$\phi(\gamma g)=\phi(g),\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\in GL(2,F),$$
and the square integrable modulo the center:
$$\int_{Z(A)GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A)}|\phi(g)|^2 dg<\infty,$$
which induces the norm on $L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)$, that is $\|\phi\|=(\int_{Z(A)GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A)}|\phi(g)|^2 dg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
In bump, automorphic forms and representations, he define an right regular representation
$$\rho:GL(n,A)\rightarrow\mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{C}}(L^2(GL(2,F)\backslash GL(2,A),\omega)),$$
In which the group action is by right translation
$$(\rho(g)f)(g')=f(g'g)$$
I want to prove this group action induces the group representation $\rho$, but when I check  the homomorphism
$$(\rho(g_1g_2)f)=f(g'g_1g_2)$$
$$((\rho(g_1)\circ\rho(g_2))f)(g')=\rho(g_1)(\rho(g_2)f(g'))=\rho(g_1)(f(g'g_2))=f(g'g_2g_1),$$
for $g_1,g_2\in G.$
So, it looks like it satisfy $\rho(g_1g_2)=\rho(g_2)\circ\rho(g_1)$, but not the form of the usual definition of the linear representation. Is bump try to define
$$(\rho(g)f)(g')=f(g'g^{-1}),$$
or there are some reasons for his definition.

How about $$[g_1(g_2 f )] (x) = (g_2 f) (xg_1)= f (xg_1g_2)=  (g_1g_2)f?$$

Oh, your right! Thank you! By the way, why he consider the endormorphism ring but not general linear group, what is the different between the representation from $G$ to $GL(V)$ and from $G$ to endormorphism ring. Is the definition between these two conditions different?
